# MySQL Watchdog warnings that disappear on flushing the cache

Tags: drupal, caching, drupal-6, watchdog

I get following type of warnings on my **Drupal Site** which usually disappear when I flush the cache

```
"Warning: MySQL server has gone away query: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (1, 'php', '%message in %file on line %line.',
```

Any idea why it happens and how flushing the cache clears it all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been [posted](http://drupal.org/node/163987) [multiple times](http://drupal.org/node/259580) to drupal.org.
Best of luck fixing the issue.

Comment: I agree that its a MYSQL problem but how does flushing the cache helps?

Comment: Maybe it somehow speeds the script execution up, allowing everything to properly finish?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `max_allowed_packed = 64M` ..... it worked for me.